# c# telegram bot. Не отправляется документ

Tags: c#, telegram

я пытаюсь отправить файл с пк через Telegram.Bot, но почему-то не получается. Несколько раз переделывал. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Вот код:

```
ITelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient("token");
    
using (var stream = File.Open("D:\\archive.zip", FileMode.Open))
{
    Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles.InputOnlineFile iof = new Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles.InputOnlineFile(stream);
    iof.FileName = "smth.zip";
    var send = botClient.SendDocumentAsync(, iof, "Сообщение");
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: "Почему-то не получается" -- это не описание ошибки. Поэтому вопрос нужно закрыть - он бесполезен для других посетителей.

Answer (score 1):

Все, я решил данный вопрос

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ITelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient("token");

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead("D:\\archive.zip"))
            {
                Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles.InputOnlineFile iof = new Telegram.Bot.Types.InputFiles.InputOnlineFile(stream);
                iof.FileName = "smth.zip";
                var send = await botClient.SendDocumentAsync(, iof, "Сообщение");
            }

            
        }
```

Comment: По сути между этим кодом и кодом из вопроса разницы нет. Добавлю только то, что вам не нужно создавать новый `TelegramBotClient` на каждый запрос, создайте бота один раз и переиспользуйте его в разных методах. И стоило бы обернуть весь код метода в `try-catch`, потому что если в асинхронном `void` методе случится ошибка, ваше приложение не упадет, вы просто ее не увидите и не будете понимать, почему код не работает.